# Deleting selected item

Tags: php, sql

Good day. I want to delete selected item by the user. But it turns out what ever button clicked by user, the first data row is deleting. Im stuck here. Please help.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
    <form  method="POST" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<?php

        $query = "select * from tblsr";
        $request = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());?>
        <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>    
                <th>Softwares</th>
                <th>Difficulty</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                </tr>
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($request)){
        ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="success">
                <td><?php echo $row['Software']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Difficulty']; ?></td>
                <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" name="change" value="Change Difficulty"/></td>  
                <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" name="remove" value="Delete"/></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php
        }

?>  </form>
```

**DELETE Query**

```
if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
 $count = count($_POST['id']); //get total number of array element
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$id = $_POST['id'][$i];
        $sql = "Delete FROM tblsr 
                Where id = '$id'";

            $success = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
            mysql_close();  

            if ($success == TRUE){

            ?>
                <script>
                    alert('Deleted.');  
                    window.location.href='manageRequest.php';
                </script>

            <?php
        }

}
    }
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. I can't see where you really submit the form.

Comment: First of all do not put <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/> in your page. especially if that is some Front end part where all users can see it. Second of all I do not see that you are using form? And third You should not use mysql_ function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: " First of all do not put <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/> in your page. especially if that is some Front end part "(What do you mean by this?) @prematch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code's problem is that you never increase `$i` ( `$i++` ) , and always your delete query affect on the first row ( id ) . you can put `$i++` in your `while` loop to fix it, but I recommend that you simply do like below  and don't bother yourself with a loop.

**Delete query :**

```
$rm = $_POST['id'];
if (isset($_POST['remove'])) {
    foreach ($rm as $key => $value) {
        $rm[$key] = "'".$value."'";
    }
    $sql = "Delete FROM tblsr 
                Where id IN(" . implode(",", $rm) .")";
    die($sql);
    $success = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if ($success) {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert('Deleted.');
            window.location.href = 'manageRequest.php';
        </script>
        <?php

    }

}
```

### your form example for delete users:

```
<form  method="POST" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <?php
    $query = "select * from tblsr";
    $request = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    ?>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>    
            <th>Softwares</th>
            <th>Difficulty</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($request)) {
            ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="success">
                    <td><?php echo $row['Software']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Difficulty']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
                    delete
                    </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php
        }
        ?> 
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="remove" class="btn  btn-success">
        delete checked user
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the part where i get the id of selected row?

Comment: its in `$_POST['remove']`. try echoing the query to find out

Comment: I tried your code and it gives me the confirmation "Deleted" but didn't execute the query

Comment: And i echoed the $_POST['remove'] and it displays nothing so its null.

Comment: try the updated answer, and try `printr($_POST['remove'])` not `echo`

Comment: This error appear when submit (Delete FROM tblsr Where id IN())

Comment: so your post is empty and the form is not proper

Comment: why dont you use checkbox for delete?

Comment: yes, I will give you an example for deleting, but try some search for **html form and php $_POST**.  look at the update

Comment: I updated two first line of my answer, I have made a mistake, try it again

Comment: Delete FROM tblsr Where id IN('191','192','193') (this error appear dude, it looks like it fetch all the ids)

Comment: No. it is the query that you `echo`ed, its correct, put it in  `mysql_query()` , it is totally okay